# Incomparable NPI decision problems

Tags: computational-complexity

Assume that there exists at least one NP-intermediate decision problem (which, by Ladner's theorem, is equivalent to P being distinct from NP).

Do there exist two NP-intermediate decision problems, $A$ and $B$, such that neither one is polynomial-time reducible to the other?

Comment: In fact, it's known that in this case the NPI problems have a very rich structure; in particular, I think there are countably many pairwise non-reducible problems, as well as countably many tiers of intermediacy. I don't have any references to hand, but I can go digging a little later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Balcazar and Diaz](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019082901132) proved that if $P \ne NP$ then there exists an infinite number of non-comparable languages in $NP$.